# Posting output from clickable tree element to iframe or region: center on jeasyui

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jeasyui how could i post the result of the tree elements on the  `iframe` inside the `region:center`?

Actual code based on [Complex Layout demo from jeasyui.com](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Layout&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jeasyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jeasyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jeasyui/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jeasyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jeasyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
<div style="margin:20px 0;"></div>
<div class="easyui-layout" style="width:auto;height:565px">
    <div data-options="region:'west',split:true", title='Menu' style="width:200%;">
        <div class="easyui-accordion" data-options="fit:true,border:false">
            <div title="Servers Index" style="padding:5px;">
                <ul class="easyui-tree"
                    data-options="
                    url:'jj.json',
                    method:'get',
                    animate:true,
                    formatter:function(node){
                                  s = node.text;
                                  if (node.server){
                                      s = '<a href=\'http://'+ node.server +'\'>' 
                                          + node.server + '</a>';
                                  }
                                  return s;
                               }">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-options="region:'center',title:'Output',
                       iconCls:'icon-ok',href:''" 
         name="center" style="padding:10px">
        <iframe name="iFrame" width="100%" height="90%"frameborder='0'>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div data-options="region:'south',split:true" style="height:50px;">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

json content:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"pick one",
    "children":[{
            "id":11,
            "server":"www.google.com"
        },{
            "id":12,
            "server":"www.altavista.com"
        }]

}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why it was downvoted twice

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by simply adding `target=\'iFrame\'`:

```
<ul class="easyui-tree"
    data-options="
        url:'jj.json',
        method:'get',
        animate:true,
        formatter:function(node){
            s = node.text;
            if (node.server){
                s = '<a href=\'http://'+ node.server +'\' target=\'iFrame\'>' + node.server + '</a>';
            }
            return s;
        }
    ">
</ul>
```